# How to use kotlin value class from java code?

Tags: java, kotlin, value-class, kotlin-companion, kotlin-inline-class

I have kotlin value class:

```
@JvmInline
value class MyValueClass internal constructor(val rawValue: String) {
    companion object {

        @JvmName("myTestValueClass")
        fun String.testValueClass(): MyValueClass {
            return MyValueClass(
                rawValue = "test",
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And now I'm trying to use my value class from java code.

```
MyValueClass test = MyValueClass.Companion.myTestValueClass("test");
```

> But I get error: Required MyValueClass provided String.

Why is this happening? Please, help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testValueClass` returns a `String` because that is *exactly* the point of value classes - they are inlined.

The whole point of value classes is that they are light-weight wrappers that has very little overhead. Kotlin tries very hard to *not* create instances of value classes.

In the JVM bytecode, value classes are replaced with the types they wrap, whenever possible, so that's why `testValueClass` returns a `String` as far as Java is concerned. The generated bytecode for `testValueClass` would be equivalent to `return "test";`.

In Kotlin, you can still use members declared in `MyValueClass` even without creating an instance of `MyValueClass`:

```
@JvmInline
value class MyValueClass internal constructor(val rawValue: String) {
    fun foo() {}

    // this actually generates a synthetic static method that does the same thing as foo:
    // public static void fooImpl(String str) { }
    // fooImpl is for demonstration purposes only, not the actual name of the method. 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // this doesn't actually create an instance of MyValueClass under the hood
    MyValueClass("Foo").foo()
    // this is translated to a static method call:
    // MyValueClass.fooImpl("Foo");
}
```

Recommended reading: [Inline value classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) in the Kotlin documentation.

In Java, however, there is no such language feature. If you want to call the `foo` method, you have to introduce an interface in Kotlin through which `foo` can be called, and provide a method that returns that interface. By using an interface type as the return type, you force an instance of the value class to be created.

```kotlin
interface MyValueClassInterface {
    fun foo()
}

@JvmInline
value class MyValueClass(val rawValue: String): MyValueClassInterface {
    companion object {
        // ...

        @JvmStatic
        @JvmName("box")
        fun box(x: MyValueClass) = x as MyValueClassInterface
    }

    override fun foo() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```java
MyValueClassInterface bar = MyValueClass.box(
        MyValueClass.Companion.myTestValueClass("Foo")
);
// now you can do
bar.foo();
```

Of course, you can also write a separate version of `myTestValueClass` that directly returns the interface.

Comment: Does the last Java code snippet actually run?

Comment: @JanItor Oh no. IntelliJ did its "this code does not compile but I will not show any errors" thing again. I'm really surprised that Java can't see the value class *at all*. Answer edited to do this in another way.