# Kotlin Inline interop: enforce boxing

Tags: java, kotlin, interop, inline

I'd like to better understand java/kotlin interop relative to inline value classes. I have some example code below with my attempts for interop, a few notes:

1. You **can** directly import inline value classes in java, i.e. `import kotlin.Result`
2. You **cannot** use their constructor methods in java, i.e. `Result.success`
3. You **cannot** use their methods once constructed in java, i.e. `myResult.isSuccess`

I created some workaround below. They work... but seem to have their own edge-cases and oddities. I have a few questions:

1. "boxing" seems to be necessary to preserve type information. Is a way to enforce boxing other than `?` (which has the negative of triggering unnecessary null checking). I tried something like `fun <T, R: Result<T>> success(value: T): R = Result.success(value as T) as R` -- it compiled but threw a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error at runtime (!!)
2. is there some other way that this can be done? Are there any modules/libraries that help with kotlin/java inline value interop?
3. it seems to be a bug that the java <-> kotlin interop here causes the `isFailure` methods to loose the success/failure status when called from Java (without explicit `?` boxing) but I'd appreciate any thoughts!

> Boxing as defined [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#representation), from which I can see that you can box by using generic and interfaces, but I don't see how I can use those to force a box AND perform logic and type checking.

Kotlin:

```kotlin
@file:JvmName("Inline")

package play

// Note: doesn't compile without `?`: 
//   incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that
//   Object conforms to Result<String>
@JvmName("success") fun <T> success(value: T): Result<T>?
  = Result.success(value)
@JvmName("failure") fun <T> failure(t: Throwable): Result<T>?
  = Result.failure(t)

// Note: java compiles without `?` BUT "failures" report isSuccess=true (!?!)
@JvmName("isSuccess") fun <T> isSuccess(r: Result<T>?): Boolean
  = r!!.isSuccess
@JvmName("isFailure") fun <T> isFailure(r: Result<T>?): Boolean
  = r!!.isFailure
```

java test code:

```java
package play;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import kotlin.Result;
import org.junit.Test;                                                    
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;                            
                                                                          
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class InlineTest { 
  @Test                                                                   
  public void testResult() {
    Result<String> rString = Inline.success("hi");                        
    assertTrue(Inline.isSuccess(rString));
    assertSuccess(rString);

    Result<Integer> rInt = Inline.success(42);
    assertTrue(Inline.isSuccess(rInt));

    Result<Throwable> fail = Inline.failure(new Exception("test"));
    // Note: fails unless isFailure using `?` type
    assertTrue(Inline.isFailure(fail));
  }

  // just proves you can pass them to java functions
  <T>void assertSuccess(Result<T> r) {
    assertTrue(Inline.isSuccess(r));
  }
}
```

Comment: I would usually consider any attempt to interact with inline classes from Java to be a bug.

Comment: it would be good if the compiler yelled at you then IMO

Comment: Kotlin can't make the Java compiler do anything.

Comment: I meant the Kotlin compiler haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot use their constructor methods in java, i.e. `Result.success`

Normally, methods of the companion object of a `value class` *can* be accessed from Java as usual. However, `Result.success` and `Result.failure` are marked [`@InlineOnly`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45763075/5133585).

> You cannot use their methods once constructed in java, i.e. `myResult.isSuccess`

This is expected. Properties and methods of inline classes are compiled to static methods taking a parameter of the wrapped type, to avoid boxing. They also have a mangled name, so you cannot access them from Java.

The `NoSuchMethodError` is a bug of either the Java or Kotlin compiler (I'm not sure). It should either *not* compile your code, or compile it without throwing a `NoSuchMethodError` at runtime. This is possibly related to [KT-26131](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26131/Incorrect-generic-method-signature-for-a-generic-function-with-a-primitive-type-as-a-type-parameter-upper-bound).

What happens here is that the `success` you wrote gets compiled to

```
Object success(Object value)
```

instead of

```
Result success(Object value)
```

The Java code looks for a method that matches the latter, which doesn't exist.

`isFailure` always returns false when using the unboxed `Result<T>`, because `isFailure` determines whether the result is a failure by checking if it is an instance of an internal `Failure` type. Obviously, the instance of `Result` you passed in from Java is not `Failure`. If you use the boxed `Result<T>?`, then an extra unbox operation will be generated.

Some Java pseudocode to illustrate the difference:

```
// for Result<T>
public static boolean isFailure(Object r) {
    return r instanceof Failure;
}

// for Result<T>?
public static boolean isFailure(Result r) {
    return r.unbox() instanceof Failure;
}
```

---

If you have control over the inline class, an alternative way to use it in Java is to have it implement an interface, [like my answer demonstrates here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77583417/how-to-use-kotlin-value-class-from-java-code/77584087#77584087).

Otherwise, I'd just write my own non-inline wrapper, that wraps the inline class.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou so much!

`If you use the boxed Result<T>?, then an extra unbox operation will be generated`

Very helpful! This is _extremely_ confusing to me though... why doesn't Kotlin auto box/unbox inline types when interacting with Java? Couldn't the "java version" of the method have this extra layer (for inline/unboxed types only)?

Without this, I really don't see how it's possible for Java to rely on a kotlin function which either accepts or returns an inline value, making interop nearly impossible. That's one thing, but the fact it compiles but fails is very dangerous IMO.

Comment: @vitiral The whole point of inline classes is to *avoid* boxing/unboxing. There is no "java version" of the method. There is only one version, which is inlined. It *might* be possible to design the Kotlin compiler so that a non-inlined version of the method for Java code to call. Though in my opinion, Kotlin inline classes should *rarely*, if at all, be exposed to Java.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the intention. I think the intention is misguided for things like `Result` however: teams just create their own `Result` type and it fragments the ecosystem. I suppose it might be argued: use a java `Result` type until you are pure kotlin and then switch the inline version for performance gains. You'll probably have a _penalty_ if you're constantly wrapping/unwrapping at every language boundary.